Android Studio Gradle sync and build taking a long time
I've just downloaded android studio and in my template project, the sync and build times are reaching 10-15 minutes. Is this normal? Is there any way to reduce these times? Build time
I tried finding the Offline Work settings that many posts say to turn on, but I cannot find those.

Definitely not normal, should be in the few seconds range. Some factors that could hamper your experience: low hardware specs, network settings that throttle downloading dependencies. I would also suspect subsequent builds to go faster due to caching.

On your first project a lot of stuff like gradle and other dependencies have to be downloaded, extracted, executed and so on. Working offline makes only sense once you have synced and built our project at least one time successfully. In general offline mode is not required if you have a persistent Internet connection.
